# What quality describes "degree of concentration of wealth"?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

Suppose I wish to propose a challenge to quantify the "degree of concentration of wealth" as it pertains to "rep" on various Stack Exchange boards. The measure being used, the [Gini index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gini_coefficient), is formally called a *generalized inequality index*, which is unfortunately *too* formal and too general.

Specifically, I'm looking at "rep" concentration as a measure of how acutely a large community is represented by a small number of individuals.

Is there a single word or expression that describes this quality? Something along the lines of "cabalistic-ness", or "activity concentrated-ness", if these were actual words?

One might invoke the same quality in other situations as well. For example, if a particular gaming website claims to have ten million users, but 10,000 particular users account for 98% of all gaming hours logged, one would say this is a _____ gaming site, or  a gaming site with acute _______.

In casual conversation, the only adjective I've heard that alludes to this meaning is *inbred*, but I'd like to avoid the negative connotations associated with that word if possible.

Comment: Why isn't your term, *concentration*, appropriate, as discussed [here](http://stats.oecd.org/glossary/detail.asp?ID=3165)

Comment: @bib: If I asked "How concentrated is this gaming site?", or "How concentrated is rep on english.SE?", barring a lengthy explanation later on, few people would deduce what I'm talking about. Having to explain "degree of concentration of wealth" or "degree of concentration of activity" isn't the end of the world, but I'm genuinely interested in knowing whether there's a term in the English language that concisely embodies this concept. It strikes me as common enough that somebody, somewhere might have coined a term for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps merely including a scale-based quantifier would be sufficient to indicate the degree of relativity between values? Something in the form of  , such as '*wealth index*' or '*cohort dominance*'?

In a general sense, concepts such as '*focused popularity*' or '*loyalist gravity*' might be closer towards describing more concentrated activity among few. I think statistics and economics are going to yield the most likely candidates here overall.

Comment: "Cohort dominance" is an excellent suggestion. Barring any "miracle words" popping out of the woodwork, I'll surely use that. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Incidentally, a gentleman offsite suggested _oligocentric_ (or _oligocentricity_, as an adjectival noun), which aren't words in any English dictionary, but whose meaning could be deduced by most English speakers through simple composition. What is your take on that?

Comment: Oh, oligocentricity is a great one too! It's quite concise and certainly implicates a distinctly small quantity. Along those lines, monocentricity might also provide a demonstrable contrast against polycentricity, inferring change in concentration towards either end.